# How do I work with "end of options" in docopt?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, docopt

I'm using [docopt](http://docopt.org/) and python 2.7. I want to implement something similar to `--` in vim. From `man vim`:

```
--      Denotes the end of the options. Arguments after this will be handled as a file 
        name. This can be used to edit a filename that starts with a '-'.
```

Thankfully, docopt already implements this, but it gives me an extra `'--'` in my argument list. For example, take this short python script:

```
"""Usage:
  doc.py FILE [ARGUMENTS ... ]
  doc.py FILE [options] [ARGUMENTS ... ]
Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen.
  -d            Debug mode.
  -f FILE       Open FILE
  -w FILE       Log to FILE
  --safe        Do not allow shell access
"""

from docopt import docopt

def main():
    print(args["ARGUMENTS"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = docopt(__doc__, version="V alpha 0.1")
    main()
```

If I call this with

```
python doc.py file.txt -- 1 2 3 -w
```

I get this:

```
['--', '1', '2', '3', '-w']
```

I would expect it to give:

```
['1', '2', '3', '-w']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you plan to put anything directly after `--`?

Comment: @ClaytonWahlstrom No, I wasn't planning on it. Right now, if I do it tries to interpret the args as options. If that's the only way to get it to work, I'd be fine with it though.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but try making the `--` optional for all usages.

```
doc.py FILE [options] [--] [ARGUMENTS ... ]
```

You can either enter options, or not and start with arguments. It will look for the first `--` if its exists.

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Wahlstrom's solution, That's not work.
So far as I know, docopt will parse everything into argument list,
There is no syntax or special usage in docopt for your use.

The best solution for now is to wipe out that "--" element before your further program flow.
Or just simply add an if case to handle it.